# How is text extracted from a PDF 'seen' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When text is read from a PDF, how is it recognized in Python3? I want to know how Python3 'sees' it so I can tell it what information to look for, keep, etc.

My ultimate goal is to read a PDF, find certain text from the read information, and create a new document with only the rows of information that match the criteria. As a rough example (in pseudo code):

-Read the PDF, if column 4 has an 'x' in it, copy that ROW to a separate file (skip if it doesn't contain 'x'), continue through until end of PDF.

-Read NEW doc, if column 1 has 'n', keep row, otherwise delete it.

I know it isn't the most ideal way to do it and I plan on fixing that part later.

Comment: Did you do any research on your own? http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

Comment: You should start by reading the source code of the PDF tool that you're using, if it's available. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a generic sense, this is very, very hard. PDF format allows "painting" of individuals words or letters, in any order, anywhere on the page.

That means what you see as a "paragraph" may or may not exists in any contiguous sense within the PDF file. The PDF reader (Acrobat, etc) merely positioned each word / letter such that they appear to be all in one paragraph.

So, you **could** render the page, then look pixel by pixel to determine how the text lines up. (This is why if you try simple cut & paste of a PDF, sometimes it comes out jumbled.)

Good news is, you'll usually get decent ordering (PDF renderers don't go out of their way to purposefully jumble text.) That's now tools like pdfminer work.

Similar for tables: **You** see them as tables, PDF sees them as a series of cells with same horizontal offset, but different vertical offsets (and not necessarily in the same order within the file.)

As others have suggested, look at pdfminer, read the PDF spec, investigate how **your** PDF file(s) are formatted.

Comment: I looked into PDF miner a bit before writing this question and tried to look at other questions as well. It's hard to go looking for something when you aren't even sure what that something is though. People are awfully quick to judge and assume on here. Thank you pbuck for the explanation. Not sure it moves me all that closer to the actual code but I did learn something